# Data Binding Label Content to Array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am somewhat new to WPF and Data Binding, it seems very powerful. I'm wondering if there's a way to have a set of labels, and have there Content property all binded to a different index in array of strings. So then as the array is updated, the labels automatically change too.

The xaml syntax is still a bit foreign to me and I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a dynamic set of labels, then you may be better off using an `ItemsControl`, and changing its `ItemTemplate` to display a label for each item in the collection that it is bound to (a collection of strings in your case).

Something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyLabelStrings}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content="{Binding}" ... />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As Bojin mentions, if you wish your UI to update if strings are added/removed from the collection, then use an `ObservableCollection` for the `MyLabelStrings` property.

Comment: Don't forget to use an observable collection to store your strings.

Comment: Oh so not an array then, something like a List<String>? And I guess I just use this ItemsControl and have a <Label> for every string in the source?

Comment: You can use a List<string> or ObservableCollection<string>, but the OC will give you collection change notifications, so the UI will update when the collection changes.